# How do you show table data on tab control?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have four different tables and I want the data from each table to be shown on four different tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Create four subforms, each based on a different table.  Place one subform on each tab's page.  If your tables are related, you'll need to either base your main form that contains the tab control on a table or query that contains your key column.

Answer (score 0):

While @Joey's answer is certainly the way to place different tables on different tabs, it can lead to a slow-loading form. In general, I prefer to have one subform control into which I can load different forms as required. The user does not see any difference, in that there is not much difference between clicking a button and clicking a tab.

```
Me.TheSubFormControlName.SourceObject = "frmForm1"
```

You can also set the link child and link master fields at runtime, if required.